# Как сделать обводку в 1 px у блоков?

Tags: html, css

Есть такой каталог, в котором каждый блок должен иметь обводку 1px.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я задаю блоку обводку в 1px. то такая обводка получается только у крайних блоков, где обводки не пересекаются. Внутри получается по 2px. Есть какие-то варианты делать обводку по 1px? Пытался делать и через тень, но так как верстка адаптивная, то там идет смещение на пиксель.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Решил задачу следующим образом:**

Задаю блоку обводку снизу и справа в 1px. А у родительского контейнера - сверху и слева. Не знаю, насколько это правильно :-)

Comment: Разметку покажите.

Comment: @Frontender Попробуйте задать разные параметры для разных сторон. В частности, для `border-top` и `border-right` установите прозрачность через rgba(0,0,0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на псевдо-таблицах и его свойство border-collapse:collapse;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.panel1 {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.panel1 .row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.panel1 .row .item {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если это просто div'ы, то можно `margin`'ы слева и снизу прописать `-1`.

```css
div {
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right:-1px; margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

Comment: Да, обычные дивы (display: inline-block или float:left, без разницы). margin: -1px тоже пробовал, результат, как и с тенями. Блоков может быть нечетное количество.

Comment: @Frontender так у вас там `div`'ы или `table`?